# How to verify text present of HTML 5 validation popup in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium IDE. I created simple form with Html 5 validation.

I have created test cases for testing form in Selenium IDE. But test case got failed when I tried to verify popup "Please fill out this field."which is html 5 validation popup using selenese command verifyAlertPresent.

How to verify Html 5 validation popup in selenium IDE?

I have attached two screenshots:

1. Form validation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT7hX.png
2. Selenium IDE Test case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6geD.png

But there is one issue that it is not working for test cases based on particular id.If I want to check for id=name in my code it worked fine but in second command if I want to check "Please fill out this field" for id=email then its taking pop of id=name and case getting passed. Here is my code:

Test case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://localhost/testform.html" />
<title>testform</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">testform</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/testform.html</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button[type=&quot;submit&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=name</td>
    <td>//*[contains(., 'Please fill out this field.')]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=email</td>
    <td>//*[contains(., 'Please fill out this field.')]</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Test Form for Selenium
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form ><center>
Name:<input id="name" type="text" required/><br/><br/>
Email:<input id="email"  type="email" required/><br/><br/>
<button type="submit" >submit</button>
<center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be html that you can check like any other element.

Try something like

```
<tr>
<td>verifyElementPresent</td>
<td>//*[contains(., 'Please fill out this field.')]</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Try that, but after detecting element please choose a better way of selecting the element.

Comment: thanks for reply,but my test worked if i put //*[contains(., 'Please fill out this field.')] in value                                                                             <tr>
<td>verifyElementPresent</td>
<td></td>
<td>//*[contains(., 'Please fill out this field.')]</td>
</tr>

Comment: you need it to be in the 2nd column where it's looking for the locator.